# Gracenote GNuser always returning null

Tags: java, android, gracenote

I am new to the Gracenote Api and I was trying to implement it in my Android app after installing the native libraries.

When I try to create a `GnUser` object it always returns *null*.

What I am doing is this in my `OnCreate`:

```
try {
    gnManager = new GnManager( ActivitySoundSearch.this, gnsdkLicense, GnLicenseInputMode.kLicenseInputModeString );
    gnUser = new GnUser(gnsdkClientId, gnsdkClientTag);
}
catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace;}
```

However, `GnUser` is always *null*.

Comment: Can you try gnUser = new GnUser(gnUserStore, clientId, clientTag, "1.0"); instead? Also, since you are developing an Android app, are you using GNSDK for Mobile instead of GNSDK?

Comment: @WYH I am using the latest GNSDK found out it was the gnManager itself that was that was returning null for some reason I think it was something in the formatting of the license string that is passed as the argument since I was hardcoding it instead of putting the license in a `license.txt` in the assets folder